# ArrayList book class

Tags: java, arraylist

Creating a Book class, below are what the methods do. I'm currently stuck on how to add methods regarding removing author by name and email. I can't upload the UML image as I'm new and dont have enough rep points.

- Create a new instance of the authors ArrayList inside the constructors.
- Implement a method addAuthor(Author author) to add the given Author instance to this Book.
- Implement a public method removeAuthorByName(String name) that uses the given String to search the authors ArrayList.  If it finds an Author object with a name matching the given String it passes the reference to this object to a private method removeAuthor(Author author).
- Implement a public method removeAuthorByEmail(String email) that uses the given String to search the authors ArrayList.  If it finds an Author object with an email matching the given String it passes the reference to this object to a private method removeAuthor(Author author).
- Implement a private method removeAuthor(Author author) which when given a reference to an Author object removes the reference to that object from the authors ArrayList.
- The toString() method shall return "book-name by n authors", where n is the number of authors.
- The printAuthors() method shall print the names of all the authors from an Arraylist.

My code :

```
class Book {

       private String    name;
       private double    price;
      // private Author[]  authors = new Author[5];
       //priavte authors =new ArrayList<Author>();
       private Map authors = new HashMap<String, Author>();
     //  private ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
       private int       qtyInStock = 0;

       public Book(String name, double price) {
          this.name    = name;
          this.price   = price;
       }

       public Book(String name, double price, int qtyInStock) {
          this.name       = name;
          this.price      = price;
          this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
       }

       public String getName() {
          return this.name;
       }

       public double getPrice() {
          return this.price;
       }

       public Collection<Author> getAuthors() {
            return authors.values();
        }

       public void setPrice(double price) {
          this.price = price;
       }

       public int getQtyInStock() {
          return this.qtyInStock;
       }

       public void setQtyInStock(int qtyInStock) {
          this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
       }

       public void printAuthors() {
            authors.values().forEach(System.out::println);
        }

       public void addAuthor(Author author)
        {
            authors.put(author.getName(name), author);
        }
       public void removeAuthorByName(String name) {
            authors.remove(authors.get(name));
        }
       public void removeAuthorByEmail(String email){
           authors.remove(authors.get(email));
       }
       public void removeAuthor(String author){
            authors.remove(authors.get(author));
       } 

       public String toString() {
          return "'" + name +"' by " + authors + " authors";
       }   
    }
```

test cases

```
Author a = new Author("Adam", "adam@gmail.com", 'm');
Author b = new Author("Ben", "ben@gmail.com", 'm');
Author c = new Author("Calvin", "calvin@gmail.com", 'm');
Author d = new Author("Danielle", "Danielle@gmail.com", 'f');
Book book1 = new Book("The House", 70.00, 5);
book1.addAuthor(a);
book1.addAuthor(b);
book1.addAuthor(c);
book1.addAuthor(d);
book1.removeAuthorByName("Ben");
System.out.println(book1);
book1.printAuthors();
```

output:

```
The House by 3 authors
Adam
Calvin
Danielle
```

Added the UML on this link : https://gyazo.com/4afc1bafa03210044fafe06650859cb0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the arraylist to HashMap.

```
private ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
```

to

```
private Map authors = new HashMap<String, Author>();
```

Change below methods-

```
public Collection<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors.values();
    }

   public void printAuthors() {
        authors.values().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
public void addAuthor(Author author)
    {
        authors.put(author.getName(), author);
    }
public void removeAuthorByName(String authorName) {
        authors.remove(authors.get(authorName));
    }
```

Comment: would you do the same for the removeAuthor and removeAuthorbyEmail

Comment: When I try this on eclipse I get an error on my test case for some reason it says, No enclosing instance of type book is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type book (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of book). for the line Book book1 = new Book("The House", 70.00, 5);

Comment: and I got this error as well .java:48: ')' expected
authors.values().forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: Personally I think it is a bad idea to use HashMap to store the Authors and using name as the key, just imagine two authors both named 'Andrew' worked on the same book.

Comment: authors.values().forEach(System.out::println); this is syntax in Java8.

Comment: you also need to make changes to your test case to reflect the changes. e.g. getAuthors() method is returning Collection

Comment: @ndlu, I agree that author name may not be a good key for the map. Instead of that there could be a custom key built from author name + book name and used it as key in hashmap

Comment: @vlaxmi, do you mean by doing something like 'Andrew-book1' will solve the issue I mentioned? I don't think so. Secondly, you seem to be basing the code around name and forgot that there is a method removeAuthorByEmail(). If I have to choose between name and email to be the key, it would have to be email as it is less likely to cause an issue.

Comment: @ndlu I gave a suggestion on implementation. I didn't mean to have something like 'Andrew-book1' rather create a new class having name and authername as it's fields then use that class's object as key on hashmap. The implementation for removeAuthorByEmail is left for the originator of this question to implement